# How do I define a user input?

Tags: python

```
from random import randint  # This imports the required modules for the program to work
character = input(str("martian,plutonian,human or dog\n>>"))  # This asks the player what character they would like to play
strength = (randint(3, 20))  # This sets the range for the strength variable
speed = (randint(3, 20))  # This sets the range for the speed variable
height = randint(120, 183)  # This sets the range for the height variable (the variables are 100x the amount that the task states)
#  The reason as to why the height value is 100x what it is meant to be is because the height is a decimal and the randint function only works with real numbers
height1 = height/100  # Because the values are 100x the required amount I divide them by 100
heart_rate = (randint(60, 110))  # This sets the range for the heart rate variable


if character: "martian"  # This makes the following only occur if the player inputs "martian"
strength += 3  #This adds 3 to the value of strength
speed +=2 #This adds 2 to the value of speed
if character: "plutonian"  #This makes the following only occur if the player inputs "plutonian"
heart_rate+=7 #This adds 7 to the value of heart rate
height1+=1 #This adds 1 to the value of height
if character: "human" #This makes the following only occur if the player inputs "human"
heart_rate+=3 #This adds 3 to the heart rate value
if character: "dog"
height-=3 #This adds 3


print("Your strength is", strength)  # This prints the strength of the character
print("Your speed is", speed)  # This prints the speed of the character
print("Your heart rate is", heart_rate)  # This prints the heart rate of the character
print("Your height is", height1)  # This prints the height of the character


file_txt=open('Character Statistics.txt', 'a',) #This creates and names the text file
file_txt.write(str("Character Statistics:\n")) #This makes a title within the text document
file_txt.write("Your strength is:") #This prints text into the text file
file_txt.write(str(strength)+"\n") #This adds the strength value to the txt file
file_txt.write("Your speed is:") #This prints text into the text file
file_txt.write(str(speed)+"\n") #This adds the speed value to the txt file
file_txt.write("Your heart rate is:")  #This prints text into the text file
file_txt.write(str(heart_rate)+"\n") #This adds the heart rate value to the txt file
file_txt.write("Your height is is:") #This prints text into the text file
file_txt.write(str(height1)+"\n") #This adds the height value to the txt file
```

Once the player is to type in a character e.g martian, this error occurs: 
 File "C:/Users/megam/Desktop/Martians/Martians.py", line 2, in 
    character = input(str("martian,plutonian,human or dog\n>>"))  # This asks the player what character they would like to play
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'martian' is not defined

Comment: Can you accept please fixed formatting and indents

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should fix intends.
Secondly `if character=="martian":`  you must change it from `:` to `==` for martian, dog, plutonian and human.

```
if character=="martian":  # This makes the following only occur if the player inputs "martian"
    strength += 3  #This adds 3 to the value of strength
    speed +=2 #This adds 2 to the value of speed
if character=="plutonian":  #This makes the following only occur if the player inputs "plutonian"
    heart_rate+=7 #This adds 7 to the value of heart rate
    height1+=1 #This adds 1 to the value of height
if character=="human": #This makes the following only occur if the player inputs "human"
    heart_rate+=3 #This adds 3 to the heart rate value
if character=="dog":
    height-=3 #This adds 3
```

Also you should change 
`character = input(str("martian,plutonian,human or dog\n>>"))` to

```
character = raw_input(str("martian,plutonian,human or dog\n>>"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions.

Comment: I have changed the code to add the == and the : but I am still getting this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/megam/Desktop/Martians/Martians.py", line 2, in <module>
    character = input(str("martian,plutonian,human or dog\n>>"))  # This asks the player what character they would like to play
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'martian' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
if character=="martian":  # This makes the following only occur if the player inputs "martian"
    strength += 3  #This adds 3 to the value of strength
    speed +=2 #This adds 2 to the value of speed
if character =="plutonian":  #This makes the following only occur if the player inputs "plutonian"
    heart_rate+=7 #This adds 7 to the value of heart rate
    height1+=1 #This adds 1 to the value of height
if character=="human": #This makes the following only occur if the player inputs "human"
    heart_rate+=3 #This adds 3 to the heart rate value
if character=="dog":
    height-=3 #This adds 3
```